# HaarCascade training stop abruptly

Tags: python, opencv, cascade, haar-classifier

I'm currently training HaarCascade Classifier. But, the classifier only runs for 3 stages then stop. It said 'Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.'

I'm using 172 pos pictures, 3020 neg pictures. Could the problem be lying in the numbers of pictures? Let me know please! Please help!

Thanks in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: that means your target quality was reached already after such few stages. If you doubt the quality (despite the numeric results), get more/harder negative samples or ask for more stages or less false alarms (which results in lowe leaf false alarm rate).

Comment: I don't know, but the classifier didn't do anything after training and being put to use @Micka

Comment: what parameter values did you choose for max false alarm rate and number of stages? 'Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.' just means that that the desired final false alarm result value from those parameters was reached already. For example 10 stages each 0.5 fa means that the training is finished once 0.5^10 false alarm rate was reached, even if that's already true after N<10 stages.

Comment: I choose 0,5 max false and 100 stages, but I don't know how to modify the false rate @Micka. Please help if you can :(

Comment: choose more/different negative samples and in your terminal window it looks like you only use 11 positive samples? You should use much more. If you don't choose "good" positive/negative samples, the training will find too simple features to divide pos from neg perfectly, which does not represent the reality well.

Comment: I use 20, and then 172 positive examples, but it keep showing me 11 @Micka. This is my command: haartraining.exe -data cascades -vec vector/vector.vec -bg negative/bg.txt -npos 172 -nneg 3020 -nstages 100 -mem 4096 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 

rem -nonsym

Comment: dont use haartraining.exe, use the traincascade.exe. The haartraining is deprecated, afaik.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172411/discussion-between-hungnguyen-and-micka).

Comment: Do you know where to find the trainCascade application @Micka ?

Comment: typically it is in the opencv binary folder and named opencv_traincascade afair.

Comment: I can't find it, is there any site to download it @Micka ?

Comment: how did you install openCV? Which version of openCV do you use?

Comment: I install ver 2.4.13, from [link] (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.13/opencv-2.4.13.6-vc14.exe/download) @Micka

Comment: there should be some .exe files in the install's /bin folder. One of them is opencv_haartraining.exe and another one is opencv_traincascade.exe

Comment: Could you help me? I have this error:                                       
                                                                                                  
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 2072706048 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError, file D:\cv\opencv_3.2.0\sources_with TextModule\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in cv::Mat::create, file D:\cv\opencv_3.2.0\sources_withTextModule\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 433 @MIcka